# How do you keep track of your past projects?

Tags: interview, resume, project

After having hard time trying to remember details of my past projects several years ago I was wondering how programmers usually keep track of that?

This kind of information comes handy with job interviews etc.

Do you write down technologies used, challenges faced etc to some kind of "jumbo CV"? Or do you just trust your memory?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some suggestions that have worked well for me:

1. Keep CV/resume up-to-date--never know when you might need it, and recording each new skill or accomplishment as it is fresh in your memory will help.
2. Record information about a project in a wiki, whether it be a team or company based wiki, or even your own personal wiki.
3. Write about new skills or topics of interest in a blog--this is a great way to record useful tips and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I have Folders..

```
Client\Project\Code

Clinet\Project\Notes

Clinet\Project\Documentation
```

I also keep all previous Vers of My CV.

But, For the most part i just trust my memory. Then go back and look for details if needed. I never needed to look for details for an interview, only when looking for code that might transfer over to a new project.

Answer (score 3):

I have a two-page CV and, each time I add stuff to it, I remove the least relevant stuff from it, to keep it to two pages.

I figure that anything I cannot remember, or which I have deemed less important than other things, is really not of interest to a prospective employer.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with 5/6 employers and all of them have different business

and almost all of them in different technologies....
so I dont think keeping any code or notes could have ever helped me.

As other pdr said I just keep removing outdated stuff from CV to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

Just like [pdr](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/115992/how-do-you-keep-track-of-your-past-projects/115998#115998), I keep the "main" part of my CV under a specific size (2-3 pages), but I also include a one-page list of technologies with experience level (in number of years).

Answer (score 0):

www.bigbucket.org allows me to have and unlimited number of private repositories. All with convinient timelines. This is what I have been using of late to keep track all my projects.